# How to highlight specific title in html when I used js for marque

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!-- javascript -->
const middle = document.getElementById("middle");
const middle1 = document.getElementById("middle1");

animate(middle);
animate(middle1);
  
function animate(element) {
    let elementWidth = element.offsetWidth;
    let parentWidth = element.parentElement.offsetWidth;
    let flag = 0;
  
    setInterval(() => {
        element.style.marginLeft = --flag + "px";
  
        if (elementWidth == -flag) {
            flag = parentWidth;
        }
    }, 10);
}

<!-- this is html itself -->

    <div id="main">
        <p class="middle" id="middle">
            Welcome to my Spectacular Show!
        </p>
        <p class="middle" id="middle1">
            Time for the show is 6:59PM EST on May 28,2022
        </p>

    </div>
```

This is js I have for creating marque in my HTML(have assignment), I need to figure out the way how to highlight the time and date only! Please help:)

Answer (score 0):

You can add them inside strong tag

```html
<div id="main">
  <p class="middle" id="middle">Welcome to my Spectacular Show!</p>
  <p class="middle" id="middle1">
    Time for the show is <strong>6:59PM EST </strong> on
    <strong> May 28,2022</strong>
  </p>
</div>
```